# Online Ubuntu man pages only showing i386?

Tags: manpage

I visited http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/conky.1.html to see which version of conky was available for that release.

[image: man page for conky]

Why is only `i386` shown? Even when I viewed any of the older releases, only `i386` was listed.

I know that the 64-bit version is available at least for 14.04 LTS because that is what I have:

```
$ apt-cache policy conky
conky:
  Installed: 1.9.0-4
  Candidate: 1.9.0-4
  Version table:
 *** 1.9.0-4 0
      500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man pages are the same for all architectures, the server seems to use the i368 packages to get them.

To see which version of a package is available for a specific Ubuntu version you can use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

If you [search for 'conky'](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=conky) you see that the version in conky is `1.10.0-1` and the package is the same for all architectures (`all`).

If you click the `wily` link of the package description you get the [details for that package in wily](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/conky).

Comment: Thanks! Bookmarked http://packages.ubuntu.com/ for future use.